# how to call vuex from a laravel blade file

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

Hi I am quite new to laravel and vue. I am trying to use vuex for the first time but could not figure out why.

I have installed vuex and have imported it in **app.js** like this

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);
```

and I am declaring the vue individually in the blade files so i am trying to do the same with vuex in the blade file

```
<script>
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            village: ''
        },
        mutations: {
            changeVillage (state,value) {
                state.village = value;
            }
        }
    });
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        store: store,
        data: {
        },   
    });
</script>
```

now the problem is vuex is not recognized and says its undefined.

i tried to declare the constant store in app.js but then this time it says store is undefined

any help will be appreciated

Comment: you're using vuejs with laravel via CDN or mix?

Comment: via laravel mix

Comment: the vue instance should be placed in main.js in view/assets/js folder

Comment: Sorry i dont get it. The thing is i dont want to declare vue in all my webpages so I am declaring vue instance only in the blade files where I need. If you mean i have to instantiate the vue in the app.js file then its a bit difficult for me since I have to change all my files.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store: store,
    data: {
    },
    methods: {
     changeVillageMethod() {
       var cval = 'somevalue';
       this.$store.commit('changeVillage', cval)
     },
    },
    computed: {
      village() {
         return this.$store.state.village;
      },
    },
});
```

Now you have access to village value and changeVillageMethod method in the template part.
I recommend reading Veux docs. https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: thats fine and i understood that part, but the problem is that it is not accessing the store variable.

Comment: well, I believe you're not registering the Vuex correctly. and Also based on your comments I don't think you need Vuex in your app while you're using Vue in one page. you can definitely do everything with Vue itself.

Answer (score 0):

try again according to the instructions:

import Vuex in the file bootstrap.js:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
...
window.Vuex = Vuex;
Vue.use(Vuex);
```

then make the following changes to the file app.js:

```
import store from './YOUR_FILE_WITH_DEFINITION_STORAGE_VARIABLE.js';
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: new Vuex.Store(store)
});
```

and your storage JS file:

```
let store = {
...
};
export default store;
```